# Sorted Indexed List using linked list on array

Tags: c++, list, sorting, data-structures

I have a project to implement a Sorted Indexed List using a singly-linked list on array.
And I have some problems when I try to do the add function.
This is how my constructor looks like:

```
SortedIndexedList::SortedIndexedList(Relation r) {
    this->cap = 10;
    this->elems = new TComp[this->cap];
    this->next = new TComp[this->cap];
    this->head = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < this->cap - 1; i++)
        this->next[i] = i + 1;
    this->next[this->cap] = -1;
    this->firstEmpty = 0;
    this->size_elems = 0;
    this->rel = r;
}
```

And this is my add function:

```
void SortedIndexedList::add(TComp e) {
    if (this->size() == this->cap)
        this->resize();
    if (this->size() == 0)
    {
        int newPosition = this->firstEmpty;
        this->elems[newPosition] = e;
        this->firstEmpty = this->next[this->firstEmpty];
        this->next[newPosition] = this->head;
        this->head = newPosition;
    }
    else
    {
        int current = this->head;
        int currentPosition = 0;
        while (current != -1 && currentPosition < this->size() && rel(this->elems[current], e))
        {
            current = this->next[current];
            currentPosition++;
        }
        if (current != -1)
        {
            int nextPos = this->firstEmpty;
            this->firstEmpty = this->next[firstEmpty];
            this->elems[current] = e;
            this->next[nextPos] = this->next[current];
            this->next[current] = nextPos;
        }
    }
    this->size_elems++;
}
```

I wanted to make sure it works and I tried to add 1, then 2, then 3 and print on each line the elements, but I 2 and 3 will not be added(The relation was <=). Can somebody help me, please? I couldn't figure out what I did wrong.

Comment: You don't have to use `this->` in order to access class members.

Comment: Hi @Gaboru were u able to fix the issue ?

Comment: Hi! Still couldn't fix it

Answer (score 0):

I think you skipped an index when initializing your `next` array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < this->cap - 1; i++)
        this->next[i] = i + 1;
this->next[this->cap] = -1;
```

You're going up to `this->cap - 2` in the for-loop (`i < this->cap - 1`), so `this->cap - 1` is never given a value.